# WP-CLI delete customers in bulk

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, wp-cli

I have a staging site and need to give an access to developers.
So, I have to delete all customers just in case.
I have below command. But I feel there should be better command.
Can you advise?

```
wp user delete $(wp user list --role=customer --field=ID --number=200000) --reassign=1
```

PS:
I delete orders with below command.

```
wp post list --field=ID --post_type=shop_order --posts_per_page=2000 | xargs wp post delete --force
```